# Is there a specific range of unicode code points which can be checked for emojis?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

Do emojis occupy a well-defined unicode range?

And, is there a definitive way to check whether a code point is an emoji in python 2.7?

I cannot seem to find any information on this.  A couple of sources have pointed to the range:

```
\U0001f600-\U0001f650
```

But for example,  has the code point

```
\U0001f918
```

which lies outside this range.

Thanks.

Comment: Might be worth investigating: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/emoji-regex  They are generating the regular expression dynamically to account for updating ranges of emojis,

Comment: I was going to ask how you even define what is or isn't an emoji, but apparently that's actually a thing the Unicode standard defines.

Comment: Isn't Python's Unicode support built in? Meaning, its tables need recalculating every time Unicode.org adds yet another SMILING KITTY? (I recall this was mentioned in another answer on a similar issue.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) supports matching by Unicode property, but unfortunately it does not (yet?) support the [emoji-specific properties](http://unicode.org/reports/tr51/#Data_Files). When it does, finding them will be as simple as:

```
>>> regex.match(ur'\P{Emoji=yes}', u'') # NOTE: Doesn't (yet) work
```

In the meantime, [here's the emoji table from unicode.org](http://unicode.org/Public/emoji/3.0/emoji-data.txt).

Comment: Note that this includes characters like `#` and `*`, because a lot more characters have `Emoji=yes` than you might expect. Filtering on `Emoji_Presentation=yes` is more selective, but it might exclude characters you *would* think of as emoji, such as RIGHT ANGER BUBBLE.

Comment: This does now work in the regex library. You can search for:
```\p{Emoji=yes}```
```\p{Emoji_Presentation=yes}``` or ```\p{EPres=yes}```
```\p{Emoji_Modifier=yes}``` or ```\p{EMod=yes}```