# Checking if string contains unicode using standard Python

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I have some strings of roughly 100 characters and I need to detect if each string contains an unicode character. The final purpose is to check if some particular emojis are present, but initially I just want a filter that catches all emojis (as well as potentially other special characters). This method should be fast.

I've seen [Python regex matching Unicode properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832893/python-regex-matching-unicode-properties), but I cannot use any custom packages. I'm using Python 2.7. Thanks!

Comment: **All** characters are Unicode characters. The simple test would be `if string:`; just test for non-empty strings. Any character Python can put in a string is part of the Unicode standard.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to test for *non-ASCII codepoints* or something similar?

Comment: Are you just checking for emoji's?  Technically, all the ASCII characters are also present in unicode as well, so you need to be a little more specific when you say you're "checking for unicode characters".

Comment: I would highly recommend reading this primer on unicode  -- http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Codepoints `[\u0100-\U0001ffff]`

Comment: @sln: not quite. This post looks like a dupe of [Is there a specific range of unicode code points which can be checked for emojis?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38730560) at this point.

Comment: Also, is this for Python 2 or 3? If for a Python release before 3.3 (so including Python 2), do you have access to a wide build (if `sys.maxunicode` is equal to `0x1FFFF` you have a wide build)? This matters because in a *narrow* build Unicode codepoints over U+FFFF take up two code-units each and are harder to test for. And that's where there are a lot of Emoji codepoints.

Comment: `Total elements: 910` good luck with that one.

Comment: Woaw.. I'll have to read up on this. Thanks for the material!

Comment: I'm converting that table to a character class, will post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point is testing 'if a string contains Unicode characters', because **all** characters in a string are Unicode characters. The Unicode standard encompasses all codepoints that Python supports, including the ASCII range (Unicode codepoints U+0000 through to U+007F).

If you want to test for Emoji code, test for specific ranges, as outlined by the [Unicode Emoji class specification](http://unicode.org/Public/emoji/latest/emoji-data.txt):

```
re.compile(
    u'[\u231A-\u231B\u2328\u23CF\23E9-\u23F3...\U0001F9C0]',
    flags=re.UNICODE)
```

where you'll have to pick and choose what codepoints *you* consider to be Emoji. I personally would not include [U+0023 NUMBER SIGN](https://codepoints.net/U+0023) in that category for example, but apparently the Unicode standard *does*.

Note: To be explicit, the above expression is not complete. There are 209 separate entries in the Emoji category and I didn't feel like writing them *all* out.

Another note: the above uses a `\Uhhhhhhhh` wide Unicode escape sequence; its use is only supported in a regex pattern in Python 3.3 and up, or in a [*wide* (UCS-4) build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446347/how-to-find-out-if-python-is-compiled-with-ucs-2-or-ucs-4) for earlier versions of Python. For a narrow Python build, you'll have to [match on surrogate pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568722/remove-unicode-emoji-using-re-in-python) for codepoints over U+FFFF.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Now if I only want to do a rough version that catches all emojis, but also other strings, would `return '\' in mystr` on some encoding of the string that would reveal all those backslashes then work?

Comment: I'm in Python 2.7

Comment: @pir: there are no backslashes in strings; you can't test for escape sequences because escape sequences are just a way to make it easier to specify a specific codepoint.

Comment: Isn't there some way in Python to reveal these escape sequences?

Comment: No, because *all characters* can be expressed with either an escape sequence or the literal value, given the right source code encoding.

Comment: The strings `u'å'` and `u'\u00e5'` and `u'\xe5'` are all equivalent.

Comment: @pir: if you mean *non-ASCII* codepoints, see [Replace non-ASCII characters with a single space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20078816)